# How Can I create Dockerfile that install dotnet sdk for existing jenkins container

Tags: asp.net, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I'm absolutely new in Docker and Jenkins in addition that I am sophomore at software world. Firstly, I would like to describe our system. We are using Centos 7 and I installed Jenkins on Docker as a container. After that I have tried using the Dotnet commands such as dotnet build on Jenkins, but I faced some errors(" dotnet: not found "). I guess I must install dotnet sdk for jenkins on docker by using Dockerfile. But I could not create Dockerfile properly. I got always some error. Can you share Dockerfile or similar issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search i have found this [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/wiqun/jenkins-dotnet/dockerfile/) and also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104954/adding-net-core-to-docker-container-with-jenkins)

This could do for you. I think you should be able to salvage useful bits for yourself.

But if there is an option id recommend your Jenkins agent just run the docker build of the dedicated .net core container through the docker socket? (as an idea of course). [For reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)